# How to reduce/remove the spaces of a GridSpec?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the next code

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 12), facecolor='#f0f0f0', constrained_layout=True)
nrows, ncols = 5, 5
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows, ncols, figure=fig, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0, top=0.99, bottom=0.1)
```

and obtain the below figure.

I use the second and fourth grid cell for plotting `*` and `=`.
Is there any way to reduce the spaces between the rows or write the symbols without using a grid cell?

[image: grid image]

Comment: What about `fig.tight_layout()`? Since this isn't a complete [mre], I can't test it.

Comment: Put `*`, `=`on the title of the subplots

Comment: @Colim has a reasonable suggestion.  You can also use the height_ratios=[1, 0.05,1,0.05,1]. keyword to gridspec

Comment: @JodyKlymak thanks mate, you just solve my issue. My fault for not reading the whole documentation.